# How to echo value from an array in according to a key value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Please help me with this array printing.

**Array**

```
 [year_2014] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 21960
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 25866
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 7840
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 424644
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 5
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 22052
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 6
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 28037
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 7
            )

    )
```

I need to echo **amount** in according to **month** so the Output will be,

**Result**

```
  21960, 25866, 7840, 0, 424644, 22052, 28037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

[image: Result eg.]

That is if a month is not present then the value need to be zero,I need all the twelve month.

My dear Good Hearts please help me to get this result.

**Some background**

project is done in codeigniter , I have messed with some for, foreach but it's not working.

Thank you.

Comment: you may want to use `usort()` function

Comment: Thanks @FaizAhmed, but can you give working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$output = array_fill(0, 12, 0);
array_map(function ($item) use (&$output) {
    $output[$item['month'] - 1] = $item['amount'];
}, $input['year_2014']);
```

or with simple `foreach`:

```
$output = array_fill(0, 12, 0);
foreach ($input['year_2014'] as $item) {
    $output[$item['month'] - 1] = $item['amount'];
}
```

Output:

```
array (size=12)
  0 => int 21960
  1 => int 25866
  2 => int 7840
  3 => int 0
  4 => int 424644
  5 => int 22052
  6 => int 28037
  7 => int 0
  8 => int 0
  9 => int 0
  10 => int 0
  11 => int 0
```

Explanation:

`array_fill` creates an array with 12 elements filled with `0` values.

`foreach` loops over `year_2014` data arrays and sets item's amounts to the `month - 1` position.

`array_map` does the same as `foreach` and can be an overkill here, but also works well.

Comment: Thank you mate, it looks promising am checking it.

Comment: Could you please add comments to as exactly what's going on in your first solution, as its a very good way to handle it, but I doubt very many people fully understand what's going on.

Comment: Great, I guess what I thought might be biggest potential point of confusion was the 2nd line, where `$output` is being passed by reference into an anonymous function that `array_map` that is applied to each node the `year_2014` array

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over each month :

```
$monthsList = array();

foreach( $year_2014 as $months)
    $monthsList[$months['month']] = $months['amount'];

print_r($monthsList); // will output array(1 => 21960, 2 => 21960 ...)

for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
{
    // You check if an amount exists for this month.
    $amount = !empty($monthsList[$i]) ? $monthsList[$i] : 0;

    // You can show date with mktime() to get a timestamp and date() to show month name.
    echo date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2014)).' -> '.$amount.'<br />';
}
```

- [mktime()](http://php.net//manual/en/function.mktime.php) will show a timestamp for selected month.
- [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with param 'M' will show months name in 3 characters : Jan, Feb...

---

HTML version :

```
echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';

  for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
    echo '<th>'.date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2014)).'</th>';

  echo '</tr>';
  echo '<tr>';

  for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++ )
    echo '<td>'.(!empty($monthsList[$i]) ? $monthsList[$i] : 0).'</td>';

  echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of the missing months or that they can be mismatched from the array index. EDIT: fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
$lst_amount = array();
foreach ($arr_year_2014 as $arr_month)
    $lst_amount[$arr_month["month"]] = $arr_month["amount"];

// Output
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month)
    echo empty($lst_amount[$month]) ? 0 . '&nbsp;' : $lst_amount[$month] . '&nbsp;';

// Output as HTML table
$html = "<table>\n<tr>\n";
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    $monthName = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
    $html .= "<th>$monthName</th>\n";
}
$html .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
foreach (range(1, 12) as $month) {
    $amount = empty($lst_amount[$month]) ? 0 : $lst_amount[$month];
    $html .= "<td>$amount</td>\n";
}
$html .= "</tr>\n</table>\n";
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

sorting:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return $a['month'] > $b['month'];
}

//$data  = your array
usort($data, "cmp");

foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo $value['amount'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to loop through each numeric month (1 - 12), and check if any of the nodes in the array have that month. So in psuedo-code:

```
for ( months ) { // 1 through 12
  for ( each node in year_array ) {
    if ( month == currentMonth ) {
      print value of month
    }
    else
      print 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hey watch the # signs they comment out the whole line

Comment: It's only psuedo-code, its not meant to be copy and pasted. The pound only means something in certain languages, so I don't really see what the big deal is, but if it floats your boat...

Answer (score -1):

Create static array for month as

```
$months = array('1'=>'Jan','2'=>'Feb',.....'12'=>'Dec');
```

then loop with foreach

```
$num_months = array_keys($months);
foreach($year_array as $key => $amount_array)
{
   if(in_array($amount_array['month']),$num_months)
       echo $amount_array['amount'];
    else
        echo "0";
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this solves his issue of having missing months in the array; this would not produce the table he's looking for